# Vectorizing Dot before or after the Function Name?

Tags: julia

I can vectorize a function using the dot notation:

```
a = Vector(0:10) .* 4
```

As in plenty of examples I read the dot comes prior to the asterisk.
However, this does not work in the following case:

```
Complex.(a,a)
```

Here the dot suddenly goes behind the function name.

Is this intended? And is there a rule?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For functions, the dot always goes behind the function name.

For operators, like `*` or `+` for example, the dot goes before the operator. However, you can enclose the operator in parentheses and suffix the dot.

To make this difference even more explicit, consider this example where we apply "multiply" with function call syntax:

```
x = rand(2,2)
sqrt.(x)
.*(x,x)
(*).(x,x)
x .* x
```

The last three commands all do the same thing.

See the corresponding sections of the Julia documentation for more: [Dot Syntax for Vectorizing Functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1) and [Vectorized "dot" operators](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators-1).

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. Is there a reasoning behind this?

Comment: I'm not certain about the reasoning but it's likely parsing related. Also, I think that `.*` when written in `x .* x` is somewhat nicer than `x *. x` but I see that this is subjective.

Comment: The dotted operator notation has a precursor in Matlab, at least. There, `.*`, `./`, `.^` etc. indicate elementwise operations. I think that's the reason for putting the dot in front, and the operator dots existed before the function dots. For functions, `foo.(x)` definitely is nicer,  but there is some tension between the two different cases.